# Greedy Algorithm for solving Horn formulas

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, boolean-logic, greedy

This is my assignment question I've been trying to understand for a couple of days and ultimately solve it. So far, I have got no success. So any guidance, help in understanding or solving the problem is appreciated.

> You are given a set of `m` constraints over `n` Boolean variables
> {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>}.
>
> The constraints are of two types:
> equality constraints: x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub>, for some `i != j`
> inequality constraints: x<sub>i</sub> != x<sub>j</sub>, for some `i != j`
>
> Design an efficient greedy algorithm that given the
> set of equality and inequality constraints determines if it is
> possible or not to satisfy all the constraints simultaneously.
> If it
> is possible to satisfy all the constraints, your algorithm should
> output an assignment to the variables that satisfyes all the
> constraints.
>
> - Choose a representation for the input to this problem
>   and state the problem formally using the notation Input: ..., Output:
>   ....
> - Describe your greedy algorithm in plain English. In what
>   sense is your algorithm "greedy"?
> - Describe your greedy algorithm
>   in pseudocode.
> - Briefly justify the correctness of your algorithm.
> - State and justify the running time of your algorithm. The more
>   efficient algorithm the better.

What I've figured out so far is that this problem is related to the *Boolean satisfiability* (SAT) problem. I've tried setting all the variables to `false` first and then, by counter examples, prove that it cannot satisfy all the constraints at once.

I am getting confused between *constraint satisfaction problems* (CSP) and *Horn SAT.* I read certain articles on these to get a solution and this led me to confusion. My logic was to create a tree and apply DFS to check if constraints are satisfied, whereas Horn SAT solutions are leading me to mathematical proofs.

Any help is appreciated as this is my learning stage and I cannot master it all at once. :)

Comment: @Elliott what i figured out so far is that this problem is related to  boolean SAT problem. I tried setting all the variables to false first and then by counter examples tried to prove that it cannot satisfy all the constraints at once.

Comment: @Elliott  I am getting confused between CSP and HORN SAT. I read certain articles on these to get a solution and this led me to confusion. My logic was to create a tree and apply DFS to check if constraints are satisfied, whereas HORN SAT solutions are leading me to mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 3):

### (informal) Classification:

So firstly, it's not the boolean SAT problem, because that's NP-complete. Your teacher has implied that this isn't NP-complete by asking for an efficient (ie. at most polynomial-time) way to ***always*** solve the problem.

### Modelling (thinking about) the problem:

One way to think of this problem is as a graph, where inequalities represent one type of edge, while equalities represent another:

[image]

Thinking of this problem graphically helped me realise that it's a bit like a graph-colouring problem: we could set all nodes to `?` (unset), then choose any node to set to `true`, then do a breadth-first search from that node to set all connecting nodes (setting them to either `true` or `false`), checking for any contradiction. If we complete this for a connected component of the graph, without finding contradictions, then we can ignore all nodes in that part and randomly set the value of another node, etc. If we do this until no connected components are left, and we still have no contradictions, then we've set the graph in a way that represents a legitimate solution.

### Solution:

Because there's exactly `n` elements, we can make an associated "bucket" array of the `equalities` and another for the `inequalities` (each "bucket" could contain an array of what it equates to, but we could get even more efficient than this if we wanted [the complexity would remain the same]).

Your array of arrays for `equalities` could be imagined like this:

[image: array of arrays, representing equalities]

which would represent that:

```c
0 == 1
1 == 2
3 == 4
```

Note that this is an irregular matrix, and requires `2*m` space. We do the same thing for the an `inequality` matrix. Moreover, setting up both of these arrays (of arrays) uses `O(m + n)` space and time complexity.

Now, if there exists a solution, {x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>}, then {!x<sub>0</sub>, !x<sub>1</sub>, !x<sub>2</sub>, !x<sub>3</sub>} is also a solution. Proof:

(x<sub>i</sub> == x<sub>j</sub>) iff (!x<sub>i</sub> == !x<sub>j</sub>)

So it won't effect our solution if we set one of the elements randomly. Let's set x<sub>i</sub> to `true`, and set the others to `?` [numerically we'll be dealing with three values: `0` (false), `1` (true), and `2` (unset)].

We'll call this array `solution` (even though it's not finished yet).

Now we can use recursion to consider all the consequences of setting our value:

(The below code is psuedo-code, as the questioner didn't specify a language. I've made it somewhat `c++`-style, but just to keep it generic and to use the pretty formatting colours.)

```c
bool Set (int i, bool val) // i is the index
{
    if (solution[i] != '?')
        return (solution[i] == val);

    solution[i] == val;

    for (int j = 0; j < equalities[i].size(); j += 1)
    {
        bool success = Set(equalities[i][j], val);
        
        if (!success)
            return false; // Contradiction found
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < inequalities[i].size(); j += 1)
    {
        bool success = Set(inequalities[i][j], !val);
        
        if (!success)
            return false; // Contradiction found
    }

    return true; // No contradiction found
}


void Solve ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i += 1)
        solution[i] == '?';

    for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i += 1)
    {
        if (solution[i] != '?')
            continue; // value has already been set/checked
        
        bool success = Set(i, true);
        
        if (!success)
        {
            print "No solution";
            return;
        }
    ]
    
    print "At least one solution exists. Here is a solution:";
    print solution;
}
```

Because of the first `if` condition in the `Set` function, the function can only be executed (beyond the if statement) `n` times. The `Set` function can call itself only when passing the first `if` statement, which it does `n` times, 1 for each node value. Each time the `Set` function passes into the body of the function (beyond the `if` statement), the work it does is proportional to the number of edges associated with the corresponding node. The `Solve` function can call the `Set` function at most `n` times. Hence the number of times that the function can be called is `O(m+n)`, which corresponds to the amount of work done during the solving process.

A trick here is to recognise that the `Solve` function will need to call the `Set` function `C` times, where `C` is the number of connected components of the graph. Note that each connected component is independent of each other, so the same rule applies: we can legitimately choose a value of one of its elements then consider the consequences.

The fastest solution would still need to read all of the constraints, `O(m)` and would need to output a solution when it's possible, `O(n)`; therefore it's not possible to get a solution with better time complexity than `O(m+n)`. The above is a greedy algorithm with `O(m+n)` time and space complexity.

It's probably possible to get better space complexity (while maintaining the `O(m+n)` time complexity), maybe even `O(1)`, but I'm not sure.

As for Horn formulas, I'm embarrassed to admit that I know nothing about them, but this answer directly responds to everything that was asked of you in the assignment.

Comment: Taking a moment for a bow down to your answer. Amazing. I never thought of this as a graph coloring problem. Here, we just have boolean variables, so I guess the same logic goes good. Do we have to include fundamentals of horn clauses in the solution?

Comment: Ayush Dave, apologies, I'm not sure what they are. I'll have to look them up. It's certainly not the SAT problem, which would obviously be NP-complete.

Comment: @AyushDave, also, the graph-colouring idea is just a way to visualise it. 'Not sure if it'll help you, but it became obvious to me how to solve it when I thought of it like that. Obviously the problem is easier to solve than the general-case graph-colouring problem, which is NP-complete.

Comment: Wow  What an amazing answer 

Answer (score 0):

Let’s take an example 110 with constraints x1=x2 and x2!=x3

Remember since we are only given the constraints, the algorithm can also end up generating 001 as output as it satisfies the constraints too

One way to solve it would be

Have two lists one for each constraint type,

Each list holds a pair of i,j index.

Sort the lists based on the i index.

Now for each pair in equality constraint check if there’s no constraint in inequality that conflicts with it.

If it does then you can exit right away

Otherwise you have to check if there’s more pairs in equality constraint lists that have one of the pairs.

You can then assign one or zero to that and eventually you would be able to generate the complete output